# Use jquery to only insert a start tag or end tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-manipulation

I'm learning that using

```
replaceWith('<section>')
```

or

```
after('<section>')
```

Will actually insert the full element in each case:

```
<section></section>
```

And that when using end tags

```
replaceWith('</section>')
```

such calls seem to be ignored.

Is there someway to disable this behavior? I need to at one point in the DOM insert a start tag, and at another point insert an end tag.

```
wrapAll()
```

I can't get to work either. I think probably something to do with what is being wrapped aren't all siblings.....

Comment: `wrapAll` is probably the correct solution. Can you post a jsfiddle that demonstrates your issue?

Comment: This is how DOM works. That's why there are wrap and wrapAll methods, before calling these functions make sure that the query returns the expected collection.

Comment: This ended up working: http://jsfiddle.net/H36UE/1/ The sample HTML more closely represents the actual DOM tree that is being met.

Answer (score 0):

i don't beleive jquery is going to allow this kind of behavior, because this will actually be allowing you to invalidate your markup.

dealing with the dom - it treats those groups of tags as "nodes".  they are group up as objects with attributes and values and many other objects reliant upon them.  so simply "moving the text" of the closing tag isn't a desired effect...

why not grab all of the stuff you want in "the middle" of your half tags... create a new element and then place your "filling" into  it with append?  something like this:

```
var theFilling = $('ul#theFilling'),
    theCookieCrust = document.createElement('section');

$(theFilling).appendTo($(theCookieCrust));

$('ul#theFilling').remove();

$(theCookieCrust).appendTo('body');
```